# User Friendly Log

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

We have developed a Project in Developer Studio everything is working fine and our Custom log is creating Custom messages in Carbon log. Our requirement is that our custom log should write in a separate file like 'Interfacing Exceptions Report' so that user can easily track the error instead of reviewing the whole Carbon log because it has too much contents as well.

Currently we have source as follows for custom log:

```
<property xmlns:ns11="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/decomposition/receiveTransform/receiveSalesOrder/model/"
                   name="OrderNumber"
                   expression="//ns11:OrderNumber"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property xmlns:ns11="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/decomposition/receiveTransform/receiveSalesOrder/model/"
                   name="OrderStatus"
                   expression="//ns11:OrderStatus"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property xmlns:ns11="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/decomposition/receiveTransform/receiveSalesOrder/model/"
                   name="ReturnStatus"
                   expression="//ns11:ReturnStatus"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="prop1" expression="get-property('OrderNumber')"/>
            <property name="prop2" expression="get-property('OrderStatus')"/>
         </log>
         <filter source="get-property('ReturnStatus')" regex="SUCCESS">
            <then>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="message" value="Your order has been created successfully "/>
               </log>
            </then>
            <else>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="errormessage" value="Sorry,there was an issue in order creation"/>
               </log>
            </else>
         </filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for sounds like  [per service logging](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Per-Service+Logs+in+WSO2+ESB) or [per api logging](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Per-API+Logs+in+WSO2+ESB).

Comment: per service logging is for proxyservice but we have VFS Projects how can we use per service logging for VFS Projects ??

Comment: What do you mean by VFS projects? Can you please be clearer. If you're using proxy services that should work no matter the underlying transport.

Comment: VFS is Virtual File System and used for reading data from flat file. In VFS projects we have no Proxy Service but we have Sequence  and 'Inbound End Point'

Comment: I don't think Inbound Endpoints have a "per inbound endpoint" log similar to proxy/api logs. The options you have for this might be to use regular VFS proxy if you have no requirement like distributed locking provided only by inbound endpoints. Alternatively you can call a proxy from your inbound sequence and use per proxy logging. You maybe able to use the local transport to prevent any overhead calling a proxy from your sequence might add. But given your requirement and the complexity of these options, maybe the best solution here is to use a another tool like DAS/BAM or Elk to filter logs.